# Send a value from one component to another in react

Tags: reactjs

I have made a Login and registration system in my MERN app and there is a problem i am not able to solve, the thing is I have made a system where when a user registers, I send him to verification page (using 'useNavigate' hook) where user receives an OTP on Gmail but the problem is I want to show the name of the user on this page like 'hi {username}' but I don't know how can I send this data from registration page and no idea how to use props here.I am adding minimal code to explain my problem :-
registration page code :-

```
const postregister = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const { first_name, second_name, email, new_password, date, gender } =
    userregister;

  const res = await fetch('/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      first_name,
      second_name,
      email,
      new_password,
      date,
      gender,
    }),
  });

  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  if (data.status === 201) {
    Navigate('/verify');
    //here i am navigated to verification page because i got status code 201 from my server
  }
};
```

This is function which triggers when someone clicks on the submit button
I am having all the user's data in a state saved already, after this i just redirected to verification page

Comment: Please include some code to support your question.

Comment: Have you try adding url queries  in code `Navigate("/verify")`, e.g.`Navigate(\`/verify?username=${xxx}\`)`

Comment: What package are you using for navigate? can you use useregister also on verify page?

Comment: You can either send it as an url parameter as others have suggested or you could look into the redux library, that way you can have shared, immutable data shared between components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the username as a parameter via the `navigate` hook:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

if (data.status === 201) {
    navigate(`/verify/${email}`);
}
```

To receive it in the other component you will need to edit the corresponding `Route` to accept the correspongin parameter:

```
<Route path="verify/:username" element={<Component />}/>
```

You can then retrieve the `username` parameter in the receiving component with the `useParams` hook:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Component = () => {
    const { username }= useParams();

    return <>Hello {username}</>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Luca it worked perfectly

Comment: Also is there any other way to pass the email to verify page without showing it in the url ?

Comment: @Samyakjain You could store the required data globally in your application using the Context API if you don't want to show the email in the URL